# Lightbox Squashed Images

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox

I'm currently having a problem with Lightbox 2. All scripts and CSS are installed correctly and I haven't changed or added code to the css and scripts.

I keep getting the result below every time and I can't seem to fix it. Any ideas on why this keeps happening?

[image: squashed picture]

Comment: Sorry,add some code and make your question better, I dont get the question at all...

Comment: Please add more specific details as to what you want, what is going wrong and especially the _relevant_ code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. Fortunately, the solution is very easy:

In lightbox.css, add the following line to **.lightbox .lb-image**:

`max-width: inherit;`

This should fix your problem. I found the answer at https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/69

Comment: Thank you, I solved it awhile. It was conflicting with Bootstrap

Comment: Also add `max-height: inherit;` if your images are being squashed vertrically